# How to replace "for" loops with an efficient algorithm in R when calculating with unique pairs

Tags: r, for-loop, unique

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to perform the below function:

```
 for(j in 1:nrow) { #begin loop over j from 1 to nrow
   xJ=vectorX1[j] #some random vector
   yJ=vectorY1[j] #some random vector

   for(ij in j:nrow) { #begin loop over ij from j to nrow
     xIJ=vectorX1[ij] #some random vector
     yIJ=vectorX1[ij] #some random vector

     if(j != ij) { #only perform on unique pairs            
        XX=myfun(xJ, yJ, xIJ, yIJ)
     }
   }
 }
```

My vectors are pretty long do the for loops are time sinks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might look into using `apply`, as it is much faster than a for-loop in R. This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/2146843

Answer (score 0):

For pairwise operations, you might find the `dist()` function in the **proxy** package useful.  You can provide your own function to replace the usual distance function.  Using the simple example below, with `nrow = 1000`, the `dist()` approach took less than half the time of your `for()` loop approach.

```
nrow <- 1000
vectorX1 <- 1:nrow
vectorY1 <- nrow+(1:nrow)
m <- cbind(vectorX1, vectorY1)
myfun <- function(row1, row2) row1[1]*row1[2] + row2[1]*row2[2]

library(proxy)
dist(m, method=myfun)
```